# Zipping using powershell

Tags: powershell, archive, php-ziparchive

I've written code to zip files older than 7 days from a source folder to a subfolder and then delete the original files. My code works best with `Compress-Archive` and `Remove-Item` cmdlets with fewer files, but takes more time and system memory for a large volume of files.
So, I'm working on a solution using 7zip instead as it's faster.

Below code does zipping correctly but not limit itself to files older than 7 days and deletes all the files from source folder. It should zip and delete only files older than 7 days.

Is there anything wrong with the code.

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
set-alias 7z "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe" 

$Days = "7"
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)

$filePath = "C:\Users\529817\New folder1\New folder_2" 
 
Where LastWriteTime -lt $limit | 7z a -t7z -sdel "C:\Users\529817\New folder1\New folder_2\ARCHIVE\$Date.7z" "$filePath"
```

Comment: `$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-7).Date` and.. aren't you forgetting `Get-ChildItem` ??

Comment: `.Date` will round down to midnight of the resulting date.  That might be fine but I don't read that intention in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are running the 7zip command correctly. You are simply telling it to add all the files from the directory `$filepath` to the archive then delete all the files.  That and I have serious doubts that 7zip can take pipeline input as your sample suggests.

Look at the [examples from 7Zip cmdline  help](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/add.htm):

```
7z a archive1.zip subdir\
```

Adds ***all*** files and subfolders from folder subdir to archive archive1.zip. The filenames in archive will contain subdir\ prefix.

```
7z a archive2.zip .\subdir\*
```

Adds all files and subfolders from folder subdir to archive archive2.zip. The filenames in archive will not contain subdir\ prefix.

I'd have to download 7Zip to test but I think you need a loop to process the files you isolated with the `Where` clause.  It might look something like:

```
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
set-alias 7z "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe" 

$Days = "7"
$Date = Get-Date -format yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm
$limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$Days)

$filePath = "C:\Users\529817\New folder1\New folder_2" 

Get-ChildItem $filePath |
Where-Object{ $_.LastWriteTime -lt $limit } | 
ForEach-Object{
    7z a -t7z -sdel "C:\Users\529817\New folder1\New folder_2\ARCHIVE\$Date.7z" $_.FullName
}
```

Note: At least in your sample you are missing the `Get-ChildItem` command.  I don't think you need to reference the `.Date` property from the `[DateTime]` object returned by the `.AddDays()` method unless you want the boundary to be midnight of that date.  Otherwise `.AddDays()` will return a `[DateTime]` naturally.

Comment: Apologies, but it's only a sample. I don't have 7Zip to test. However, by the description you gave I'm certain that the 7z command in your sample is incorrect.  It's very clear from the documentation that's what would happen.  You need to debug and put your focus there and you'll nail it.